# ParseObject doesn't find any methods android studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have downloaded sdk from parse and I added the .jar to 'libs'. Then, I configured my gradle (at same level to src...) and this looks like:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
}
```

the case is that I didn't have any problems when I added ParseUser o some like that to my code, but now I want to add this code:

```
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Course.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Comment.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Video.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Category.class);

    Parse.initialize(this, APP_ID, KEY_ID);
```

This code does work on eclipse, but I don't know why on Android Studio 1.0.1 doesn't work...

When I write:

```
ParseObject p = null
```

Does Work! but When I write ParseObject. and I press CTRL+SPACE to get help for IDE, doesn't find any methods.

I am going crazy... This is my first post, I hope that you can understand me, if I explained not so good, please, let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so ParseObject does not have a red line under it?

Comment: What version of the Parse SDK are you on?  Given that you're also on a very old version of Android Studio, it's possible your Parse SDK doesn't have those methods.

Comment: To Blundell, No, When I write ParseObject p = null; I don't have any errors but when I write ParseObject.registerSubClass(); yes, I get a red line under it because 'no suggestions'.

Comment: To Michael, the last version, I use 1.9.1... and I check the code of the library and I found that method, but the problem is that doesn't find ANY methods... :(

Comment: Did you try manually adding the import statement?

Comment: Yes, imported everything of library

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.... incredible but I just had to rebuild the project and the problem disappeared.